# How do I convert CURL to Guzzle HTTP?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I am trying to convert curl request to Guzzle:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://shopify.s3.amazonaws.com' \
        --form 'key="tmp/436699194/bulk/4fed3d0c/bulk-customer-insert-file.jsonl"' \
        --form 'x-amz-credential="AKIAJYM55WGJDKQ/20210625/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"' \
        --form 'x-amz-algorithm="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"' \
        --form 'x-amz-date="20210625T105058Z"' \
        --form 'x-amz-signature="6c02b9f5dff8dd57d04bcdef3e3e602cad09fa719ffd84d"' \
        --form 'policy="policy"' \
        --form 'acl="private"' \
        --form 'Content-Type="text/jsonl"' \
        --form 'success_action_status="201"' \
        --form 'file="https://files.com/uploads/imports/12841.jsonl"'
```

The curl request works properly, but when I try to transfer It to Guzzle, It stops working and returns an error:

```
 $response = (new Client([
                'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data']
            ]))->post('https://shopify.s3.amazonaws.com', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'key' => 'tmp/436699194/bulk/492f28bf-d0c/bulk-customer-insert-file.jsonl',
                    'x-amz-credential' => 'AKIAJYKQ/20210625/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request',
                    'x-amz-algorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
                    'x-amz-date' => '20210625T05058Z',
                    'x-amz-signature' => '6c02b9f5dcde2cafa719ffd84d',
                    'policy' => 'policy',
                    'acl' => 'private',
                    'Content-Type' => 'text/jsonl',
                    'success_action_status' => '201',
                    'file' => 'https://files.com/uploads/imports/12841.jsonl',
                ],
            ]);
```

Error:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Conflicting query string parameters: acl, policy</Message><ArgumentName>ResourceType</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>acl</ArgumentValue><RequestId>P6V9RFVQNMW249XD</RequestId><HostId>GhCPTKO2P/VysP90bvFI5lXiyzF0IlSX//rotCB/hTtxy8tQMcwqKh8j397VdMKYvD1UL+aEgMo=</HostId></Error>
```

The documentation states: "You must use a multipart form, and include all parameters as form inputs in the request body."

Comment: tried using `multipart` instead of `form_params` ? with a bit of luck, that's the only thing you're doing wrong.

Comment: @hanshenrik yes, no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Using multipart instead of form_params worked perfectly!